# Cannot install 10.10 on new 32 GB SSD in DELL Mini 9

Tags: ssd

Cannot install 10.10 or any other distro on new 32 GB SuperTalentSSD. It is recognized by Bios, but Error says: Input/output error during write on dev/sda. Installed 10.04 on 16 GB SuperTalent SSD earlier without problems. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me when trying to install ubuntu on my ssd drive. The reason was, that the drive was not formatted at all. I used a live usb stick to get the computer up and running. Using G-parted (can be found under system or you need to download it via synaptics) I was able to format the drive and than the install worked flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a live usb stick and got Dell mini 9 running, but G-parted unable to format the SSD apparently due to an input/output error.