# Getting error 5 while installing via USB

Tags: 11.10, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“errno 5 - input/output error” when trying to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop with Ubuntu 11.10 , 64-bit version through a usb drive

I get the following error:
This particular error is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often available from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler environment.

My hard disk is brand new and I also ran tests which showed that it was fine.
Also, the USB works fine on other machines.

Should I run 32 bit version? I was using windows 7 64 bit version earlier on the same machine, but its hard disk got corrupted and I don't have a bootable windows cd/dvd to reinstall.

I read in a couple of forums that replacing/removing ram does the work. I have one stick of 2gb which is 2 years old and ran fine on windows, so that's not an option for me.
Please advise.

Comment: I am facing exactly same problem. Initially I thought that running memory tests will remove this problem but no success... @ALL - Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated. Here are two threads... I hope this will help in some way.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1894282 http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install