# Problems installing Ubuntu server and desktop

Tags: installation

*google translate*

Good afternoon I'm new to linux, I have to install a proxy and to them I decided on Ubuntu, the problem is that it took several days trying to install Ubuntu on any version and when installing i get error [Errno 5] input / output error
says that is because the disc (cd or dvd) is bad or faulty change it and save all denuevo but I get the same error try changing the hard drive to see if my drive had no problem and I also get the same error , the machine where I want to mount the Ubuntu is a P4 with 1GB rAM and 40GB disk is more than the minimum requirements for even so I get the error ... I would like someone could help me thank you very much .....

---

*original*

Problemas al instalar Ubuntu server y desktop

Buenas tardes soy nuevo en linux, tengo que instalar un proxy y para ellos me decidi por Ubuntu, el problema es que llevo varios dias tratando de instalar Ubuntu en cualquiera de sus versiones y al momento de instalar me sale error [Errno 5] input/output error
dice que se debe a que el disco (cd o dvd) esta malo o defectuoso lo cambie y grabe todo denuevo pero me sale el mismo error trate de cambiar el disco duro para ver si no tenia problema mi disco y tambien me sale el mismo error, la maquina donde quiero montar el Ubuntu es un p4 con 1gb ram y disco de 40gb, es mas de los requerimientos minimos por aun asi me sale el error... me gustaria que alguien me pudiera ayudar muchas gracias.....

Comment: And why did you changed the hard drive if it's telling you that the CD or DVD is the one that has problems?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 4):

You may have a corrupted CD/DVD in which you burned Ubuntu on. Try re-downloading the iso files and burn them again.

Tranlation to spanish:

A lo mejor tienes un disco CD/DVD malo. Baje el iso de Ubuntu otra vez, y quemalo o tostarlo otra vez.

If you can't install using the CD/DVD, try using the USB thumbdrive method

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button

Spanish:

Si no se puede instalar usando el CD / DVD, pruebe a utilizar el método de USB pendrive.