# The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, cd, live-environment

The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:

> [Errno 5] Input/output error
>
> This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard
>   disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower
>   speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often
>   available from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk
>   is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler
>   environment.

Please Suggest Me As I Deleted The Previous Version 11.10...So My Installation 12.04 is stuck

I am using the Live USB.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried several ways of installing this latest version - nothing worked, so I downloaded and installed Ubuntu 11.10 and clicked on upgrade software. Ubuntu 12.04 downloaded and installed like a dream - pity you uninstalled the earlier version.

Answer (score 0):

Boot off the usb stick and when it shows the keyboard icon at the bottom hit a key.  Then select the option to check the files on the stick (I forget the exact words).  If that throws an error then you have a problem with the data on the stick and need to re-burn it.