# Ubuntu CD Installer crashes with "erron5 input/output error"

Tags: installation, live-cd, iso, ubiquity, toshiba-satellite

I had 12.04 installed on a Satellite l635. I wanted to start over with a fresh install because I had experimented with a bunch of different things, and computer was getting glitchy and random freezes.

I used the same ISO I used for original install, and it keeps saying that the installer crashed with a `erron5 input/output error`.

Tried an older ISO for 11.10 I had used in the past with same issue. To see if it was disc or computer (not a great idea) I tried the 12.04 ISO on another laptop. Now I have 2 laptops with no OS. Both discs however live boot on both systems.

**Please help**. I've searched forums and can't find the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried downloading a fresh ISO?

Comment: Please verify your ISO and burnt cd with md5sum directions can be found at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: I just got done with a fresh iso download, and no, the numbers on new download do not match. It came directly fom the ubuntu page, unless it bounced me somewhere els. Checking old disc in a seecond. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 1):

Try not to download iso with a download manager if you are using one . Downloading via torrent is a good option . The md5sum should match , else it shows that your download is corrupt .