# Can't install due to "udeb file failed the MD5 checksum verification" error

Tags: installation, live-usb, live-cd, 12.04

I have been trying to get Ubuntu 12.04.1 (desktop-i386) running on my laptop. Have burned a boot-able CD containing 12.04.1. It allows me the option of **Trying out** Ubuntu before installing, but the installation fails. It cites an `input/output error Errno5`.

I have tried burning another disc and using another USB disc drive, but they all give the same result as above.

I then downloaded the `alternate-i386` and loaded it onto a boot-able USB flash-drive. During installation, it produced an error as well, and selecting the option to check the CD's integrity produced the following:

```
The ./pool/main/1/linux/nic-usb-modules-3.2.0-29-generic-pae-di_3.2.0-29.46_i386.udeb file failed the MD5 checksum verification. 
Your CD-ROM or this file may have been corrupted.
```

Proceed to check the integrity of the aforementioned CD produced the same message as well. Any help guys? Really want to get Ubuntu up and running.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 2):

You should check the hash sums of the downloaded ISOs. You can get the hash sums (md5sum or sha1sum) from http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/.

To check the md5sum:

- Go the directory where you downloaded the ISO.
- Compute the `md5sum`:

```
     md5sum ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
```

- Check if the sum is same as the one given on the link above. In this case the correct `md5sum` should be `e235b63c02644e219b7bf3668f479c9e`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides checking the md5sum, try to avoid the fancy programs on the ISOs as those caused errors for me on 12.04.1 and try a simple dd. Assuming your USB stick is /dev/sdb, do a:

```
sudo dd if=<path to iso> of=/dev/sdb
```