# Keep trying to install always throws error help!

Tags: dual-boot

So I was installing 12.10 on my Asus g74sx laptop... Did everything the tutorial told me to do yet I keep getting an error saying that there was an error of input/output.. That I should check the hard drive and see if it needs replacement.

I tried with 2 DVDs and did format twice my usb to fat 32 and mounted the image file for 12.10... No idea what is going on. Please help! Mmm I cannot add an image... I'll comment with the link to the error!

[image]

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=9jhgus&s=6

Comment: possible duplicate of ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the .iso image ONLY from www.ubuntu.com/download/
Use a torrent [available at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads ] if you're using a slow connection.
Burn onto a new DVD at a slow speed using a system different fro the previous one.

If it still fails, you can try installing on your HDD using another machine. For eg, I failed many ties while installing FreeBSD on my laptop (and on a friend's laptop of same make & model), but it went smooth on both HDDs when I used them in my Desktop!

Good luck!

Comment: @Hector Did it work? If it did, upvote the answer that worked the best; and mark the problem as 'solved'. Check FAQs about the procedures. You are a new user, I see that, and that's precisely the reason I'm telling you this: so that you contribute the best to the community. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First check md5sum of ubuntu 12.10 iso file you downloaded. If it corrects than may problem in DVD you burned. Burn Another DVD at low speed. If you face problem then It should be faulty hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ISO download if it is complete. Sometimes when you download a torrent it isn't really completed even though it states otherwise. Same can happen through direct download as well. Boot from you USB flash and you should not have problems.

Also go ahead and use CHKDSK utility on the drive you are trying to install. This might fix an issue if it finds one.

Your last option is alternate ISO. Go ahead and try if none of the rest works.