# trying to install ubuntu but getting error input/output error

Tags: system-installation

I was trying to install ubuntu from live-usb and I get error input/output error. I tried boot repair disk for ubuntu.

[Here is the output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1363690/)

Any help is appreciated. I tried testdisk without any luck. No clue how to get it back.

Comment: possible duplicate of [“errno 5 - input/output error” when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/q/65830/65926)

Answer (score 1):

The I/O error is on your DVD drive. Burn a new DVD, try a slower speed and check all md5sums.