# Ubuntu Installation Fails from cd and usb stick

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.10. I have downloaded the .iso file.
I tried to burn the file to a DVD using infra recorder but it gives an input/output error.
Then it fails to burn and cd drive ejects the cd.

I tried using usb stick too. But after pressing the create button, it gives an error:
cannot open file as archive.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried UNetbootin?

It can create a bootable usb drive using the.iso file you downloaded.
It is available for Windows, Mac and Linux. You may have more luck with it.
Here's a link: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/