# Error code 5 when installing

Tags: system-installation

Im using a single core 2.8Ghz pc with 1Gb ram and 400Gb harddrive.

On installing either 12.10 or 12.04 I get an Error Code 5 input / output error halfway through the install.

I have tried 5 CD's of different speeds 3 hard drives (although I want to use the 400Gb one) 2 different CD rom drives and 2 different IDE cables.

After reading through the forum I have booted Ubuntu into "try it" mode and accessed the disk utility which confirms the harddrive is healthy. I have unmounted the drive, formatted and remounted, I have also repartitioned the drive.

Im not doing anything fancy, its a vanilla install and Im selecting default options.

Still getting the same error, its driving me mad.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used 10.04 to migrate to 12.04.

Once in 12.04 it was apparent that one of the DIMMs was faulty.

Replacement of DIMM fixed issue

Answer (score 0):

Is your 1GB of Ram one stick or two? If it's two try removing one and trying to install again! http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/errno-5-input-output-error-639355/#post3332486

Comment: Ok I have swapped the memory from another machine (only 512Mb), fingers crossed

Comment: Good luck! If it's succesful you should just be able to put back in the 1GB of RAM after you've it installed and set up.

Comment: No still failed and it always fails on the Any Questions install screen

Comment: Ah, sorry I'm all out of ideas!

Comment: mmmmm 10.04 installs without a problem......bizarre

Comment: Hmm, maybe try upgrading to 12.10 from within 10.04 and see if it works that way?