# Error with Wubi Installer- Ubuntu 13.04 desktop

Tags: wubi

I'm having problems installing Ubuntu 13.04 desktop. I've download the wubi installer on my Windows computer.

When I open this file using WinRar & run `wubi.exe`, it attempts to install Ubuntu but when the system restarts and the installation proceeds, an error occurs while copying files to HDD:

```
The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:
[Error No. 5] Input/Output error
```

I tried mounting the iso file using Daemon Tools, but it doesn't let me install directly but asks for a CD/DVD.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 1):

You may have some bad sectors on target HDD.

To check `sda1` volume for bad sectors in Linux run `fsck -cc /dev/sda1`. For drive `C:` in Windows it should be `chkdsk c: /f /r`.

IMHO `chkdsk` way is may be more suitable as it will remap bad blocks on HD drive while Linux `fsck` simply marks such blocks as unusable in the current file system. Quote from `man fsck.ext2`

```
-c This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks. If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or directory. If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test
```

Source: ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Comment: So, the file is usless now :'(
Is there any option to multiboot ubuntu with windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Don't open the ISO with `WinRar`. Place the desktop ISO in the same folder as the `wubi.exe` from http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ and then run `wubi.exe`. Then it will find and use the ISO you downloaded.

You can also copy the `wubi.exe` off the ISO (use WinRar for that if you like). But mounting the ISO or extracting the contents are not what you want to do.

Comment: Does that mean I need to download the desktop iso again?
I have that iso, so can I just extract wubi.exe off it and place them both on same folder?

Comment: @1lastBr3ath no, use the existing ISO. Yes, extract `wubi.exe` from it or download it separately (both work and it's only 3 MB to download).

Comment: Nop, it's not working :(
Is there not any way I can multiboot both ubuntu & windows?

Comment: @1lastBr3ath There might be but for that I need to know what the error is.

Comment: I mean, can I use the file (I have) to multiboot ubuntu with windows?
I also tried booting from usb drive but the error was same, error copying files to HDD - Input/Output error.
It takes a lot of time to download the file, you know.

Comment: @1lastBr3ath assuming the ISO is good (have you [checked the md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows)?) yes you can write it to a USB/DVD and install from that, or use it with Wubi, or a VM.

Comment: I did check the md5sum. I already tried booting from USB but the error remains. Now, I think I need to download a new iso file that supports multiboot with windows. You can rather suggest me the one best for a newbie and can multiboot both windows & ubuntu.