# Ubuntu 12.04 installation input/output error

Tags: 12.04, installation

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my system since tomorrow, I know there newer versions of Ubuntu available, but still I want to install this version only.

I'm repeatedly getting the same error when I try to install Ubuntu on my system. I checked the md5 hash of the ISO file i downloaded but it is correct. I'm installing Ubuntu from my USB drive.

Please help me out, I need an OS to be installed on my PC. Because I don't have one.

Comment: which software did you used to create bootable ubuntu usb?

Comment: I used Universal USB installer as recommended on the ubuntu site

Comment: try unetbootin.And don't forget to change the boot-order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“errno 5 - input/output error” when trying to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 0):

Input/Output error usually means that the drive has failed to read or write correctly. Are you sure that your HDD is good, and not dying?