# input/output error during write on /dev/sdb during Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, 14.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a clean hard drive but it gives an error:

```
input/output error during write on /dev/sdb
```

What should I do to fix it? Thanks in advance I haven't tried anything as I am a newbie.

Comment: If you are installing from USB, then there is a problem with the USB. Ubuntu wasn't correctly copied on USB drive.

Comment: make sure that your USB drive is properly connected.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 1):

"I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a clean hard drive":   "input/output error during write on /dev/sdb" indicates that the system is unable to write to /dev/sdb.

please begin by opening a terminal and providing the output of:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
```

If this fails, it's likely either the drive or the cable connecting it is bad.

Answer (score -1):

Try disk destroyer("dd") command, google for disk destroyer command , be extra careful on which partition it is being used. If this does not work then you device is broken, there is no way to fix it.

Comment: this is disk destroyer command if you want: "sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M"

Comment: `dd` stands for "Data Description" not disk destroyer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29