# The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk, but the .iso file checksum is correct

Tags: 14.04

I have 64-bit dell N5110 laptop. During Ubuntu 14.04 installation, I received this error. I know the error is common, but I didn't find an answer, so please read below.

---

> [Errno 5] Input/output error
>
> This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard
>   disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower
>   speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often
>   available from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk
>   is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler
>   environment.

---

I've had this error before, but back then I had problem with Ubuntu .iso file (checksum wasn't correct). However, this time the checksum is correct. Moreover, I used both Ubuntu (Start-up app) and Windows (Universal-USB-Installer) ways for making bootable usb. Both of them are giving me this error. If it means something, in "md5sum.txt" file on bootable usb the hash doesn't match with the correct on.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install Have you tried the suggestions there? Test laptop hard drive, memory and try a different USB drive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 2):

maybe you will be surprised like I am. I recently encountered the same problem while trying to install ubuntu 14.04 on my other laptop (i3 Dell-Vostro). What I did is; I used Universal-USB-installer to create a bootable usb, then tried installing, it didn't work, I've been reading  lots of suggestions here with no luck. **Solution** - I simply decided to use another software which is rufus (https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create a bootable usb, then it worked, just like that. I am surprised, as simple as that. So now I think that Universal-USB-installer didn't copy all necessary files,I hope this is helpful.