# Need help installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, 14.04, partitioning, system-installation

I am a complete Linux noob. I burned the latest Ubuntu ISO to a DVD and tried to install it from the disk. My original intention was to install it alongside my Windows, but somehow I ended up creating a new partition table.

When I realized I had gone past the option to *Install alongside* I pressed back and chose the option and clicked install. The installation was almost finished and then I get the error number 5 (`errno 5`) saying

> hard drive or disk may be faulty

So I decided to reboot my computer. But now if I don't boot from the "faulty" disk, my computer won't boot at all: it will just be a black screen.

I keep getting the errno 5 error no matter how I try to install. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: To find out what the errno 5 - input/output error means see this question: [“errno 5 - input/output error” when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install). You also need to get some information about how to recover your original Windows installation, step-by-step. The alternative to computer repair service if your hard drive has bad sectors is to simply swap out the hard drive and try installing Ubuntu again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a disk i/o error at the sector it is trying to install to. Go into advanced options in install, then resize the windows partition to be slightly smaller and the ubuntu partition to start slightly sooner on the disk. See if the error disappears or if it happens later on and post back

Comment: Could you be a little bit more descriptive, like i said i'm a complete noob. I don't see an advance options. when install after making the partition smaller it says that there isn't a root

Comment: so click "something else" after I believe the wireless or just the language setup, then select the partition that matches the one with windows, resize it to be slightly smaller, like by 5 or 10 gb, (relatively small) then delete the one with ubuntu, and create a new one that fills the entire leftover free space. Click on "change" after doing so and select "use as ext4", "format", and set the mountpoint to "/"

Comment: in which partition should i set the mountpoint to "/" the free space or the one i think windows is using? i just tried it with the free space and i got the errno 5 again.

Comment: it should be the free space. Did the errno occur in almost exactly the same place?

Comment: yes it did it happened when it was almost done

Comment: Try burning the disk again, I had the exact same issue when I first tried installing ubuntu, it turned out it was a bad disk write

Comment: yea see the problem is this is my only computer and if i take the boot cd out i won't be able to use the computer anymore, it only has one drive so i can't burn an iso while the boot cd is in.

Comment: what did you use to burn the disk?

Comment: try this, download from their site a new iso, and use the startup disk creator in the live session to burn to a USB stick, then use that to install ubuntu

Comment: tried that, for some reason my computer won't boot from the usb it just stays in black screen

Comment: You need to find a friend to burn one or something, even just a computer at work/school can probably do it

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem, as it seems many others have too!

From the research I've conducted, some have stated that using another USB stick has helped.  Others have commented that the problem was resolved by burning a different iso file to the USB stick - for example using the torrent version as opposed to the iso available from the Ubuntu website.  In another forum somebody suggested that their problems were fixed by installing unetbootin and writing the iso to the usb using this rather than Startup Disk Creator.

Although I'm yet to find the answer to my install issue, I hope one of these solutions is of use to you.