# Error in loading of Ubuntu 14.04 installation DVD

Tags: system-installation, dvd

The installation gets to the screen of Ubuntu where it's loading, I click the left button to see code and here's what it says is happening:

```
stdin: Not a typewriter
Generating locales...
    en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
chroot: can't execute 'glib-compile-schemas': Input/output error
chroot: can't execute '/usr/lib/user-setup/user-setup-apply': Input/output error
install: invalid user 'ubuntu'
install: invalid user 'ubuntu'
Using CD-ROM mount point /cdrom/
Identifying... [bac8495d27ebe9f23250907977f69e73-2]
Scanning disc for index files...
Found 2 package indexes, 0 source indexes, 0 translation indexes and 1 signatures
Found label 'Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)'
This disc is called:
'Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)'
Copying package lists... gpgv: Signature made Thu Apr 17 01:35:09 2014 UTC using DSA Key ID FBB75451
gpgv: Good signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Ket <cdimage@ubuntu.com>"
Reading Package Indexes... Done
Writing new source list
Source list entries for this disc are:
deb cdrom: [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)]/trusty main restricted
Repeat this process for the rest of the CDS in your set...
*Starting Mount filesystem on boot                       [OK]
*Starting Signal sysvinit that the rootfs is mounted     [OK]
*Starting Populate and link to /run filesystem           [OK]
*Stopping Track if upstart is running in a container     [OK]
*Starting Mount filesystem on boot                       [fail]
*Stopping Mount filesystem on boot                       [OK]
```

Then there's a lot of things that happen in one second, and I couldn't write it down. It sends me to a screen that says:

```
General error mounting filesystems
A maintenance shell will now be started
CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and reboot the system
```

(Sorry if there's any mispelling, I translated it from handwriting. And by the way I'm not from USA, I don't know why it says "en_US.UTF-8... done", and the time marked in the signature seems to be also from the USA.)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Input/Output error, I suspect your CD/DVD reader may be failing, you should maybe try making a [bootable USB drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Comment: Tried with a bootable USB drive and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help man. It has happened to me before, so it was the first sensible thing to try.