# I cant install Ubuntu! It wont work!

Tags: 14.04

The error "errno 5 input/output" shows up when copying files! Please help! BTW I used the bootable USB.

Comment: Did you try a web search for this exact message?

Comment: Following question should help you out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/501505/ubuntu-14-04-errno-5-input-output-error-during-installation

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost check whether your ISO image with which you have made bootable is proper. Verify the checksum for the same. If that's not the issue then following steps should do the needful:

1. Choose **"Try Ubuntu"** instead of **"Install Ubuntu"**.
2. Open terminal **[Ctrl + Alt + T]**.
3. Enter command:

> ubiquity --no-migration-assistant

4. Try installing again.

Still if problem persist do refer [Error Number 5: Input/Output Error while installing Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/465136/error-number-5-input-output-error-while-installing-linux) for more solutions and explanations.

Comment: @NathanCornett If the answer has helped, do mark it as 'Accepted'.