# Insallation Help - Input/Output Errors when Trying to Install

Tags: partitioning, windows, acer

Well, I'm not very good at computers, but my Acer Windows 8.1 CPU has had it's partition or hard drive deleted. I tried resetting my computer with a windows boot usb, tried refreshing and I kept getting errors that wouldn't let me. That's when I downloaded Ubunutu unto my USB hoping if I got rid of everything and just downloaded Ubunutu and made it my main OS I would be fine, but I was wrong.

When I try to install, I get:
This computer currently has no detected operating systems, what would you like to do?

I select Erase disk and install Ubuntu
Errors I get: 
Input/Output error during read on dev/sdc I click ignore 11 times until it goes away, then I get:
The creation of swap space in partition #3 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sdc) failed.

Comment: Is there any way to fix that ?

Comment: I've converted my comments into an answer below.

Comment: Probably the reason why your Windows died on you is that your drive is actually dead. Installing Ubuntu on top of a dead drive will not magically resurrect it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/65830/65926

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is bigger than can be fixed here.  Input / Output errors typically point at failing disks or bad hardware.  Those errors can result in the kind of "No OS Found" messages you were seeing, as well.

If the issue is hardware in nature, and the hardware is dying or faulty or failing, there's no real way to fix that except to replace the hard drive. Given that you were having irreparable issues in Windows 8.1, it looks like hardware failure might be the issue.

I'd suggest taking your computer to a technician for testing and diagnosis of hardware issues, or reach out to the manufacturer of the computer, because it sounds like a dying disk if Windows was also giving you errors and such.