# Error installing ubuntu [Errno 30]

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, lenovo

I try to install ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS in my laptop, but an error ocurred all the time. Sometimes it is Errno 5 and others Errno 30, but the message is almost the same:

> This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard
>   disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower
>   speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are available
>   from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk is old and
>   in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler environment.

I am installing from an USB, I have do:

- Check MD5SUM (correct)
- Try with two different USB installer, UUI and rufus.
- Try width two different USB devices, both of them 16GB.
- Try the option Check disck for defects (no errors found)
- Memtest86+ (no errors)

<del>This last I don't how to intepret, here is a image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6j59by9lxgh403b/20141213_233539.jpg?dl=0</del>
EDIT: solved! I was using old memtest86+ version, the last version works fine and I have not found any error.

<del>Is there any problem with the memory?</del>
What is causing this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues, one fix that may work is to redownload Ubuntu to a different USB again, or, if you can, install from a CD disk. CD's tend to be more stable, and they worked well for me. If the system is saying that there is no errors, you may want to attempt to remove a ram stick, and try with one. 
Finally, in the image you provided, it shows the RAM as 0Mhz(?!) which could hint at faulty memory. Best luck with this issue, it seems likely to be a hardware problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already try with two USB and now also with a DVD but the same error occurs. I have solved the RAM issue, I have edited the question. So, with other steps can I do to find what is causing this error when I instal Ubuntu?

Comment: in question already inform you that the all possible try are perform for the installation then why repeat that question in the answer

Comment: Virus, I don't think I get that, the original question was edited to show the solved memtest issue. After that, the answer in my question was disproved.