# Error 5 Input/Output error during installtion through USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb, hard-drive

I have followed every possible issue but still not avail to solved the problem

hard disk fully formatted
Windows 7 / 8 installed without any issue after getting the issue 
check memory issue / Test pass 
Check DIsk error - found nothing 
tried with all the version found same issue (14&12)
Download various version through Torrent or direct download and with LT version
Formatted full 500 GB hard drive for the issue but still not resolved

unable to rectify the issue

For making Bootable I use 
Rufus & Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.8 but same issue arises

hard disk formatted like the following
Logical drive 5GB - Swap area
Primary partition ext4 15GB - /
Free partition ext4 - /home

Please guide me on that issue

Comment: possible duplicate of ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 1):

I can barely follow your full question, so I'll just answer the "Input/Output error during install through USB", assuming it's a USB input/output error.

- If you could post the exact error messages (should be some in `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg`, maybe even with `lsblk` to see which drive is which) that would help show if it's USB errors or HD errors.

I get those occasionally with flash drives & card readers, sometimes a different USB port helps, or a different wire, hub, or card reader. And sometimes the USB device itself just starts "going bad," or doesn't get along with the other USB parts.

For installing Ubuntu, if you booted with the `toram` option (in the grub boot menu, F6 I think brings up the "other options" menu & lets you manually edit the startup line) that would copy the whole Ubuntu iso into ram at startup, so if it can successfully do that you could unmount & unplug the USB after booting and really see if the IO errors are caused by something else.

Or if you can't boot with `toram` & get too many IO errors, that points to a USB/hardware problem.

- Tried the USB on a different computer? Is it bad there, hence a bad USB drive?
- If the USB is good, then maybe the HD is giving the errors, and probably failing?
- **Use a cd/dvd to install Ubuntu?**

Comment: I have used different USB ports and with other computer also but i used to get these error when i tried to install ubuntu whatever version i use i get these issue

Comment: The error is ""errno 5 - input/output error"

Comment: try installing using a cd/dvd?