# Can't install ubuntu [Errno30]

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

Ubuntu installer retrieve this error while copying files during ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS installation in my laptop:

> This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard
>   disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower
>   speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are available
>   from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk is old and
>   in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler environment.

I have already make some checks but can't find what is causing this error:

- Check MD5SUM (correct)
- Try with two different USB installer, UUI and rufus.
- Try width two different USB devices, both of them 16GB.
- Try with a DVD
- Try the option Check disck for defects (no errors found)
- Memtest86+ (no errors)

What can be causing this error?

Comment: How far into installation? Are you connected to the internet during installation? are you able to boot to a live environment(try Ubuntu)? and have you re-downloaded the OS before each attempt? Is your laptop running on battery or wired power?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu)