# Ubuntu will not install from USB

Tags: boot, usb

I realize this question has been asked before, but I'm completely new to Ubuntu, and didn't understand half the terminology being used, sorry.
When I had Windows 10, I downloaded the image file for Ubuntu, and then used Rufus to put it on the USB. I restarted the computer and selected the USB, and gave Ubuntu a try. I liked it and so decided to try and install it.
When I tried to install Ubuntu via the installer on the desktop of the test run mode, it couldn't complete and gave errno 5. Since I gave Ubuntu the ability to write over basically everything, I no longer have any other OS, since I thought Ubuntu would just install (Yes I know, what an idiot). I need to know how I can get past this error and install Ubuntu properly.
Side note: I visited this page for the answer: ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)
But the terminal outputted:
Fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
fsck.ext2: Permission denied while trying to open /dev/sda1
You must have r/w access to the filesystem or be root

Answer (score 0):

Since this is referencing ext2 we can gather it's trying to do something with the kernel. Given that it's during installation I'd go with that you *do* have bad sectors. The risk of continuing to run an HD with a bad hard drive is all up to you to assume, but the hassle isn't worth it. Just buy a new HD.

**If you want to verify you have a bad hard drive**

1. Boot from Live USB
2. Open up *Disks* from the launcher
3. Select the disk from the left
4. The top right contains SMART data and self-tests

Comment: After trying to do the SMART data and self-tests options, it just gets stuck at 10% and refuses to move any further.