# Errno 5 input/output error

Tags: system-installation

I am facing a havoc situation, I choose install Ubuntu in place of Windows 10, and now I don't have any OS on my computer and Installation of Ubuntu showing error 5 every time I reached out to install it. 
It shows Errno 5 input/output error message and suddenly installation gets stop. 
Type of installation: through Bootable USB drive 16 Gb 
Hard drive of computer: 78 Gb
RAM of computer: 2 Gb

What to do? 

I don't have any other computer, I tried it so many times but nothing works. 
Now I have a pc which is not more than a Brick.

Comment: Hello. I recommend doing some editing and provide more information. It's on the border of being a rant instead of a question.

Comment: Thank you for updating it with more information. Possible duplication of this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install

Comment: I crying because I don't have any other computer right now and the only thing I have a Bootable USB.

Comment: Hello. Please read this question posted before, it may help you. http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install

Comment: How can I check the bad sector on HDD, I don't have any OS on the computer right now.

Comment: Your bootable Ubuntu usb will have a live version of Ubuntu Desktop environment for you to follow the solution in that question.