# Ubuntu 16.04 Errno 5 Input/output error when installing using USB

Tags: 16.04, usb, 64-bit

I'm installing Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit) using a Pen drive but during the installation, I get the I/O error, however sometimes prior to this, some other errors appear saying I am missing a certain file and then I have the option to Cancel, Retry or Skip (the same error doesn't always appear every time during the installation)
I'm on a HP Compaq dx2300 microtower.
I have tried looking at other solutions, but they do not seem to work for me.

Comment: What other solutions have you looked at? What is the exact error you are experiencing? You can paste it on pastebin.org and place the link here for us to see.

Comment: I tried the installation again and these errors came up in this order: http://pastebin.com/3UxDyafr . I usually get this though: "The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk: [Errno 5] Input/output error This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are available from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler environment."

Comment: Other solutions I looked at were that I should burn my CD/DVD at a lower speed and another was a terminal command which had to do something with CD/DVD burning, but I'm using a pen drive for the installation

Comment: Also, If it helps to know, I tried to install Ubuntu once before and kept getting Errno 5 Input/Output error. However, I just kept trying again and again and after around 20 tries, It installed without any errors.

Comment: You may want to run a check on your ram and/or harddrive to verify they are all ok.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Here's how to do a ram check, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MemoryTest. To do a hard drive check, https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html

Comment: This is what the Hard drive check said: Disk is OK, one attribute failed in the past (31° C / 88° F)
Here's a picture to the results to the Ram check:
http://i.imgur.com/1X6bvfa.jpg

Comment: Wow, you need to troubleshoot your ram. Looks like you have some bad ram. Try taking one stick out at a time until you narrow down which is bad, try the good one in different slots.

Comment: After removing the 1gb ram, I got two errors about miasing files but after having to skip them, I installed Ubuntu but after restarting, the screen stayed pink. Afterrestarting again, I got this: http://imgur.com/dyIp5PN

Comment: You only have 1gb ram in the machine? Do you have another good stick you can troubleshoot with by swapping it in?

Comment: I have a 2gb ram in the machine. What do I troubleshoot after swaping the pen drive with another one?

Comment: The physical ram in the machine. Try different known good sticks in different slots until you have working ram in working slots. That picture above was showing you that you had some bad ram.

Comment: Are both my rams are bad?

Comment: Apparently, while taking out the ram I had unplugged a wire which was causing this: imgur.com/dyIp5PN After plugging it back, I first get this screen: http://m.imgur.com/LJsESjq and after selecting Ubuntu I get this screen: http://m.imgur.com/427zhwx

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days of trying, I found a solution for my problems (similar to yours). I tested on different OSes running on different computers (win7 32-bit & win8.1 64-bit), different USB, different Ubuntu version (14.04/16.04 32-bit/64-bit). All of them return the same error at the same process. Although checking disk before installing warns that `splashfs` file has an error, errno 5 is not from there.

Finally, I found a solution: Set partitions for the USB you want to install Ubuntu onto as shown.

[image]

The problem could be from the first FAT32 partition for boot loader. The size of that partition should be lower than 256MB. If you set bootloader in another disk, this partition could be ignored.

The free space is used to create a normal partition which stores data after finishing installation of Ubuntu.