# Unable to install Ubuntu 20.04 on the machine and VirtualBox

Tags: 20.04

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop since its pre-release, every time when I downloaded the ISO file and try to install it in VirtualBox, it always gives this message:

[image: The Error Message when trying to install Ubuntu Budgie]

I've check the MD5 SUM of the ISO file, it is correct, so I thought maybe something wrong with the pre-release ISO? So I waited until the official release, I tried again, same result. Today I went out and perform a clean install on my another PC, it runs well and give me no issues.

PS: the screenshot is taken when I tried installing Ubuntu Budgie but the same error occurs as well in the Gnome version of Ubuntu.

But when I try to perform a clean install on my laptop, the same error message pops out again.

I am very sure that it is not the problem with the USB Drive/ISO file, I even ran a CHKDSK on Windows 10, and it reports that my hard disk has 0 errors.

Comment: Does Virtuabox work when you try to install other OS Guests?

Comment: Ya, I have a kali system running fine there. I am very sure that the problem is not with the VirtualBox because it gives me this error as well when I try installing it onto the laptop.

Comment: Uh-oh. An input-output error may (or may not) be seriously bad news. It means that the installer is trying to communicate with the Virtual HDD, and getting no response or bad response. Possible hardware problem, or possible VirtualBox (Windows) bug.

Comment: But why does this happens as well when I'm trying to install it to my harddisk? But I ran chkdsk on windows, it gives zero error and shows that the disk is fine.

Comment: Do you have Docker installed with Hyper-V enabled?

Comment: I confirm exactly the same phenomenon. Verified for Ubuntu 20.04 and Kubuntu 20.04 on the latest VirtualBox6.1.10/Windows10. Windows has all of the latest updates for June 2020: Windows 10 OS Build 19041.329. I've run memory tests and found no problems. This is a total showstopper for Ubuntu and Kubuntu and may mean the end of 10 years of my using these distros.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when installing Ubuntu 20.04 in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239382/error-when-installing-ubuntu-20-04-in-virtualbox)

Comment: @mpkossen It's not such a good duplicate because the answer to this question is different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I've found the issue here, this is because I have WSL2 enabled on Windows, for some reasons WSL2 and VMs cannot co-exist. After I disabled WSL2, the VM worked.

PS: WSL1 still works though, I think this is due to the fact that WSL2 is actually running as a VM.

Comment: VirtualBox 6.1.12 is supposed to work with HyperV turned on. I's sure I read somewhere that VB was changed to work in conjuction with HyperV.
In fact already installed VMs boot just fine with HyperV and WSL2 installed.
But I can't get a new VM to install due to the Check error when booting from ISO.
It's not the ISO, as it installs fine with VMWare 15.5.6.
So suggest you try VMWare Player which is free too.

Answer (score 0):

See here for the full answer on how to disable Hyper-V: [Error when installing Ubuntu 20.04 in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239382/error-when-installing-ubuntu-20-04-in-virtualbox). WSL2 uses Hyper-V components, which causes this issue.

Comment: If the answer to a question is another Ask Ubuntu question, it is better to mark THIS question a duplicate.