# Trouble installing Ubuntu 20.04 on VirtualBox 6.1.10 on AMD Ryzen 4800H

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, 20.04, msi, amd-ryzen

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 ISO downloaded directly from Ubuntu website with correct SHA256 Checksum but encountering some problems shown in pictures. The machine is MSI Bravo with AMD Ryzen 4800H. Host is Windows 10 ver 1909. SVM enabled on BIOS. The option to enable nested VT-x/AMD-v is, however, grayed out in VirtualBox settings.

I tried download from different mirrors with correct checksum and still got errors. Does anyone have any suggestion?

[image: Errno 2:]

[image: librythmbox:]

[image: Errno 5:]

Comment: Found the answer that fixed the issue -> https://askubuntu.com/a/1240518/1092983