# found 1 error in files before installing

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb-installation

i know this question was asked before but none of them was helpful and solved anything.
my problem is when i want to install ubuntu 20.04, before getting into installing as you know there is a file checking process but it gives me an error : 'found 1 error in files'
i checked my iso and its ok (with hash).
i tried to install this on another system it gave error like this as well.
i tried to install from DVD but again it gave me the error.
and i even tried to install it with this error but in the middle of installing it gave me "The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:

[Errno 5] Input/output error

This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard
disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower
speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often
available from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk
is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler
environment.  "
please help i desperately need this!!
also im on bios (Legacy) and i have the minimum requirements for the installation.
i even tried the older versions but it didn't work (Errno 5)

Comment: Help is what we do, but "idk" doesn't help us help you. If you can update your question with the exact error messages that you're seeing, then it might be possible for someone to assist 

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu)