# Keep getting problems during Ubuntu 22.04.2 installation - Errno5 input/output

Tags: boot, usb

Ok, so I screw up my last actualization of Ubuntu - I was not paying attention and during this I encountered a lot of problems, in the end my laptop stopped working. I tried to reanimate it, but to no avail - it seems that my entire system is not responding.

Therefore, I tried to repair this by installing new Ubuntu - however, during installation (no matter my choices, be it install completetly new or recover old system) i keep getting „Errno 5 - input/output error”. I changed my USB stick, i used different entrances, I checked my ISO file. It seems the problem may be connected with problems on my filesystems.

I tried to check my filesystems with fsck commands, but it keeps saying my that i can’t do that and All answers on the internet tell me, that i need to reboot it to kill all my processes to be able to umount it. However, if i do reboot it, i can’t go back and have to boot it from the start. Is there any other way to kill all programs or to remove Errno5 problem?

Comment: Error 5 (input/output) means you have a hardware error that Ubuntu cannot fix. It means your storage device is not responding as expected. Determine if the errors are your USB stick or your hard drive, and replace that faulty hardware.

Comment: Commands like `fsck` do not check disks for errors, they perform file-system checks which are *logical* checks of the metadata of the file-system; your disk can be 99% dead but if the part of the disk that contains that metadata still works `fsck` will work. What device did you get the IO error (ie. hardware error), as that part of the detail is necessary (ie. read the context & full message(s) including those just prior in logs). As we don't know what you were doing; we only know you have hardware problems (*being limited to only what you provide which included no context*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu)